# Linux how do I execute a bash script from the parent directory?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a script called GenerateDTIPubSub and if I call it from its file location using the terminal (which I opened in the same file location):

./GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub

works fine.

How do I now execute the script while in the folder above? 
Example: `./cfg/GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub`

Which does not work(reminding you that I've also opened the terminal in the folder above)

edit: It executes but the bash script but can not find the perl script that it executes unless the bash script is executed from its directory (if that makes sense)

`./GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub` GenerateDTIPubSub then calls the DTIFramePubSub function that calls a perl script, this path works fine

`./cfg/GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub` this does not work, it can't find the perl script

> Can't open perl script "Scripts/DTIPubSub.pl": No such file or directory

but the path for the perl script does not change only the bash file path

Comment: Does `./cfg/GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub` not work?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: What is your question here? Is `cfg` a folder inside the 'folder above'? In that case you answered your own question.

Comment: Whether you can call a script from a different directory does depend a lot on how the script has been written

Comment: You could try `cd cfg && ./GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub`, i.e. temporarily changing the directory before you call the script

Comment: In response to the edit: What exactly doesn't work? As @NaN said we need the error message. Is the script itself throwing an exception? Can it not be found? Short reminder that on Linux, generally speaking, the file and foldernames are casesensitive. So if your folder is spelled `Cfg` that would explain why the script can't be found

Comment: This reads like what @john had in mind. Somewhere inside the bash script the current path is used.

Comment: @john yes you're onto something with path needing to change in the script itself, that helps

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

To work around the problem, you can use the following:

```
( cd cfg; ./GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub )
```

The parens create a subshell to avoid changing the current work directory for anything but the `perl` process.

---

The underlying problem is that `GenerateDTIPubSub` assumes the current work directory is the script's directory. What follows are instructions on how to fix that.

1. The quick and dirty approach:

   Add the following:

   ```
   use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
   BEGIN { chdir($RealBin); }
   ```
2. The more sensible approach:

   First, add the following:

   ```
   use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
   ```

   Then replace

   ```
   "Scripts/DTIPubSub.pl"
   ```

   with

   ```
   "$RealBin/Scripts/DTIPubSub.pl"
   ```

   You may need to do multiple similar fixes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must (temporarily) change the current working directory before calling your script. You can do that with the following technique

```
cd cfg && ./GenerateDTIPubSub --DTIFramePubSub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path of the Perl script inside the base script needs to be changed to include the `/cgf`